# Is there any tool to check access to C# internal members from other name-spaces?

Tags: c#, internal

I have two loosely coupled components **A** and **B**. Each component is a set of C# types. Many of those types are internal. All components are to be compiled together into the same assembly and sit in the same project.

The fact that **B** is dependent on **A** and not vice-versa can be checked with the new VS2010 feature [layer diagram](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/02/18/favorite-vs2010-features-layer-validation.aspx). But it seems there is no way to check that **B** is not touching internal parts of **A**.

I cannot separate components into different assemblies and make compiler to check this for me, because then there would have to be too many assemblies, and I would have to IL-merge them, and that is the price I don't want to pay.

I'm looking for some instrumental solution for this problem. I need some tool that could take description of what I consider components as input and verify that whatever dependencies between components there are they do not touch each other internal stuff.

I've heard that [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) could do something like that by applying some attribute to internal types. On the weaving stage PostSharp verifies that there is no acces to those types from different namespaces. That would be enough for me, but I don't remember attribute name and couldn't find it.

Can anyone remind me the attribute name in PostSharp or come up with any other tool?

Comment: I mean groups of classes in one project I don't want to split into separate assemblies because than those assemblies would be too small.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use you use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), which will use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate the necessary diagrams and show the relationships.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this? Namely to check if my one group of classes don't touch internals of another group of classes